# How to update the POM version from Jenkins pipeline after build if tests are successful

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I inherited 2 projects, one depending on the other, both Maven projects building with Jenkinsfile.

Project B has dependencies on some modules of project A.

Right now the version in the pom.xml of project A is hardcoded, as is the version of the dependency in project B. Versions are managed in the Jenkinsfile, but not updated in the pom.xml. This sometimes causes problems with local builds for project B.

I would like the versions in the poms of the modules of project A to be increased to reflect the builds, instead of being hardcoded.

The suggestions I found online seemed old, and I am not sure they are relevant anymore. I am looking to use the best possible approach.

Jenkinsfile:

```
env.VERSION = "${env.BUILD_ID}-${(env.BRANCH_NAME).replace('/', '-')}"
if (env.BRANCH_NAME == "master") {
    env.VERSION = env.BUILD_ID
}

    stage ('Checkout') {
        checkout scm
        gitCommit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim()

        sh "git config user.email email@email.email"
        sh "git config user.name 'jenkins-username'"
        sh "git tag -a -f -m 'Jenkins CI Build: ${env.BRANCH_NAME} ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}' ${version}"
    }
    
    stage ('Build') {
        withCredentials(......) {
            ansiColor('xterm') {
                sh "docker build --build-arg VERSION=${env.VERSION}  --target build -t sometag:build ."
                docker_images.each{ image ->
                    sh "docker build --build-arg VERSION=${env.VERSION} --target ${image} -t ${rootRepo}/${image}:${env.VERSION} -t ${rootRepo}/${image}:${gitCommit} ."
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

pom.xml:

```
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1234</version>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of the plugin https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/

We do this with the following code where `versionTag` is the version we want to update pom.xml with:

```
def pomFile = 'pom.xml'
def pom = readMavenPom file: pomFile
pom.version = versionTag
writeMavenPom file: pomFile, model: pom
```

Remember to commit and push the pom.xml afterwards.